# Illegal character error while using Google graph API in Android

Tags: android, httpclient, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google graph API (image) to show some data in the form of PIE chart. [http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=p3&chd=t:41.86,26.00,21.78,10.36&chdl=User998|User591|User671|Others](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=p3&chd=t:41.86,26.00,21.78,10.36&chdl=User998%7CUser591%7CUser671%7COthers), this link gives a pie chart when viewed in browser. But, when I am trying to get the response using HttpClient, I am getting illegal character error. I am using following code to get the response

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse;

           try {         

    String chartUrl = "above url";
//Here, I am getting illegal character error.
               HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(chartUrl);
               getRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
               httpResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
               HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

               if (entity != null) {

                   InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                   bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);

                   instream.close();
               }
         }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
              //TODO
           }
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?
Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character in question is |, you can work around by using %7C instead in the URL and it should work.